# Cast IEnumerable(Of String) to my sub-classed List(Of String)

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, types, ienumerable

I have this class that inherits from a list:

```
Public Class TextLines : Inherits List(Of String)


End Class
```

Now, how I can cast a return value of type `IEnumerable(Of String)` to my custom Class?

Real example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim lines As TextLines
lines = CType(File.ReadAllLines(Me.filepathB, Me.encodingB).ToList, TextLines)
```

It throws an invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?

```
Dim lines As New TextLines()
lines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(Me.filepathB, Me.encodingB));
```

or expose the constructor that takes the `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Thanks but I would like to solve it in the right way by understanding why cannot do the conversion If an Ienumerable(of T) can be converted to a List(of T) using the ToList function, and my class inherits from a List(Of T), Then I don't understand why can't cast it, or how to solve it. thanks anyways

Comment: @ElektroStudios its the same argument that every square is a rectangle but not all rectangles are squares. you can't cast to a subclass.